# R Row_number df

Tags: sql, r

Hello I added a row number id arranged by a category to the data frame already. Column 1 list the ID which is is linked with categories assigned in CAT column.

```
ID CAT
1  A
1  B
1  C
2  A
3  B
3  C
4  A
4  B
5  C
6  A
```

How to remove all ID from list that have only CAT "A"?

This would be result:

```
    ID CAT
    1  A
    1  B
    1  C 
    3  B
    3  C
    4  A
    4  B
    5  C
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:sql]?

Comment: @r2evans I was hoping to be able to use sqldf or some other way using sql in R I think the row_number sql function doesnt work in sqldf. So I used dyp

Comment: I believe that including the tag alone is not sufficient to communicate that (many questions are tagged incorrectly). In the future, if you are open to (or prefer) a particular package/R-dialect, then please be explicit in the question (comments are not always enough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wanted a SQL variant:

```r
sqldf::sqldf("select * from DF where ID in (select ID from DF where CAT != 'A')")
#   ID CAT
# 1  1   A
# 2  1   B
# 3  1   C
# 4  3   B
# 5  3   C
# 6  4   A
# 7  4   B
# 8  5   C
```

(One can also use `select distinct ID ...` on the inner query, I don't know if it'll have an impact on large-ish data.)

Data

```r
DF <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), CAT = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Will this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(!(n() == 1 & CAT == 'A') | !all(CAT == 'A'))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID CAT  
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     1 B    
3     1 C    
4     3 B    
5     3 C    
6     4 A    
7     4 B    
8     5 C
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      ID CAT  
   <dbl> <chr>
 1     1 A    
 2     1 B    
 3     1 C    
 4     2 A    
 5     3 B    
 6     3 C    
 7     4 A    
 8     4 B    
 9     5 C    
10     6 A
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `ave` + `subset`

```
subset(
  df,
  !ave(CAT == "A", ID, FUN = all)
)
```

gives

```
  ID CAT
1  1   A
2  1   B
3  1   C
5  3   B
6  3   C
7  4   A
8  4   B
9  5   C
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, ID %in% ID[CAT != "A"])
```

-ouptut

```
  ID CAT
1  1   A
2  1   B
3  1   C
5  3   B
6  3   C
7  4   A
8  4   B
9  5   C
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
    CAT = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```